# Can I automatically create high resolution screenshots in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, screenshot

I'm using Firefox 60 (don't ask me why). I can create high resolution screenshot from GCLI with command:

```
screenshot /tmp/screenshot.png --dpr 2
```

But I can't do the same via cli or js.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can execute GCLI command using JS:

```
let gcli = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/devtools/gcli.jsm", {});
let environment = gcli.createEnvironment();
let requisition = new gcli.Requisition(environment);

requisition.exec({
  command: "screenshot /tmp/screenshot.png --dpr 2",
  args: {}
});
```

Refer: https://gist.github.com/Gozala/6126308/

Comment: Thanks a lot, but during execution I've got: `ReferenceError: Cu is not defined`